# systemd resolve doesn't respond to queries

Tags: server, systemd, netplan, systemd-resolved, systemd-networkd

I'm getting dns failures on some of the servers with Ubuntu Server 17.10 or 18.01. I can't resolve addresses unless I go direct to the nameservers (ie with dig @1.2.3.4 ...)
It can't resolve the simplest of queries:

```
$ host localhost
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

/etc/nsswitch.conf:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

/etc/resolve.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search xx.uk xxx
```

netstat output:

```
$ netstat -pluten
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      102        209799     7876/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 192.168.x.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          45394      2673/dnsmasq        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7030          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          26916      3236/docker-proxy   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          23759      1925/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::7946                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          48402      2076/dockerd        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          23761      1925/sshd           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4789            0.0.0.0:*                           0          26906      -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           102        209798     7876/systemd-resolv 
udp        0      0 192.168.x.1:53        0.0.0.0:*                           0          45393      2673/dnsmasq        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           0          45390      2673/dnsmasq        
udp        0      0 10.x.x.x:68          0.0.0.0:*                           101        2702       7218/systemd-networ 
udp6   22592      0 :::7946                 :::*                                0          48403      2076/dockerd
```

Yet systemd-resolve is working:

```
$ systemd-resolve localhost
localhost: 127.0.0.1%lo
           ::1%lo

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 201.5ms.
-- Data is authenticated: yes
```

There's no output from systemd-resolved even in debug when making requests

Comment: Is resolv.conf a symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf ? Otherwise it is possible the libc resolver might be confused...

Comment: Yes its a symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
If I modify it to point to one of my nameservers, resolution works.

Comment: hi @RichardCollins did you ever figure out what was going on? I figure it's some iptables rule or something blocking the query but I can't seem to figure it out..

Answer (score 1):

I do not have any advice on how to *fix* systemd-resolved's stub DNS responder properly, **but I can suggest a workaround**:

1. Enable `nss-resolve` for applications that use NSS
2. Tell applications that *do not* use NSS to contact upstream nameservers directly

For (1), change your `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
hosts: files resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
```

For (2), link `/etc/resolv.conf` to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

The simple workaround if you know for sure what DNS server would you like to use is just add them to `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`. This works for me:

```
sudo vi /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
```

Uncomment the line `#DNS=` and add your preferred DNS servers (space separated).

```
DNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Then do:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```